# Prove surjectivity of $ \alpha \mapsto (x\mapsto S(\alpha x)) $ by construction.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $ F $ be a field, $ K/F $ a finite field extension and $ S : K \to F $ a nonzero $ F $-linear map, i.e. $ S \in \operatorname{Hom}_F(K,F) $.

It can be shown that the map $ K \to \operatorname{Hom}_F(K,F) $ defined by $ \alpha \mapsto (x \mapsto S(\alpha x)) $ is an isomorphism of vectorspaces over the scalar field $ F $. One way of doing this is by showing it is well-defined with 0-dimensional kernel and using the rank–nullity theorem.

However, what I want to do is show surjectivity by construction. Given $ T:K\to F $ nonzero $ F $-linear, how can I construct $ \alpha $ such that $ T(x) = S(\alpha x) $?

Comment: I am no expert, but I assume the result is false if you drop the finiteness assumption? If so, I think that's a hint that the construction you seek may be difficult to find.